# Delete a column containing 0 from a matrix in Scilab

Tags: matrix, zero, scilab

I have a matrix looks like

1 2 3 4 5 6

0 1 0 1 0 1

Now I would like to delete all the rows which containing 0, so that the result should be

2 4 6

1 1 1

I have search other similar topics but cannot work it out. Could you help me plesase?

Answer (score 3):

Let us use the example you've listed:

```
-->A = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 0 1 0 1 0 1]
 A  =

    1.    2.    3.    4.    5.    6.  
    0.    1.    0.    1.    0.    1.
```

First, in Scilab terminology, you are deleting all *columns* that contain 0, according to your example.

Here is the code that allows you to do this:

```
-->[row, column] = find(A == 0)
 column  =

    1.    3.    5.  
 row  =

    2.    2.    2
```

This line returns the coordinates of all elements which have a 0 in the matrix A.

You can delete all columns that have a zero, thus:

```
-->A(:, column) = []
 A  =

    2.    4.    6.  
    1.    1.    1.
```